# MVC 4 EF 5 ID field changing value on Model Binding

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So here is my situation I have a model:

```
public class Label
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string en { get; set; }

    public string fr { get; set; }

    public string es { get; set; }

    public string ar { get; set; }
}
```

the controler action looks like:

```
   public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Criteria criteria = db.Criteria.Find(id);
        if (criteria == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        Label label = dbl.Labels.Where(l => l.ID == criteria.Label).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(label);
    }
```

and post:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Label label)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            Label L = dbl.Labels.Find(label.ID);
            L.en = label.en;

            dbl.SaveChanges();

        }

        return View(label);
    }
```

and a view that looks like:

```
@model RAPID.Models.Translation.Label

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Criteria</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.en)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.en)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.en)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.es)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.es)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.es)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fr)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fr)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fr)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ar)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ar)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ar)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

The problem I am having is for some reason when I check the label.ID in the Edit(get) the value is the correct string value associated to that field. Now when I check this same value label.ID on the post this value has changes to an integer value which seems to be corresponding to the order of the record in the table. Also on the edit view the value thats displayed is the number value vs the correct string value. So I am thinking it has something to do with the model binding but not sure how to resolve it.

Was wondering if anyone knows what the problem may be.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is because you are on the edit page with the id, and then you do a post and it overrides your string ID with the id from the url (routevalue). Not sure. Your code is a bit messy here some things:

```
Label label = dbl.Labels.Where(l => l.ID == criteria.Label).FirstOrDefault();
```

replace with:

```
Label label = dbl.Labels.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ID == criteria.Label);
```

also
criteria.Label is a string I guess or is it the item? You should name it LabelID. Because it is confusing^^.
I think you can fix all this by renaming your ID in label class to something like LabelID or something. Then the system won t get confused with the  2 ids.

Comment: Yeah criteria.Label is a string ... changing the ID to LabelID will require to many other changes right now to other parts of the application but I agree that it should be changed and will prob fix the problem. I dont understand the difference between the first item you pointed out and think its just preference

Comment: well the 2nd one is shorter, I think SQL linq is smart enough that the performance won t be faster but still. Writing code that does nothing is kinda a bad habbit imo. You can also try to change the HttpGet parameter, from (int id = 0) to (int labelid = 0). Those changes shoudn t require alot of work.

Comment: I agree with the shorter code and will use your suggestion going forward :) ... ok so I changed the Get method from int id = 0 to string id that way I just pass in the label string directly instead of looking it up again but your suggestion also works to just change the name of the input parameter to something other than ID ... I guess when it comes to binding URL takes precedence to everything else ... Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create an accessor in your model such as public string `LabelID { get{return ID}; set{ID = value}; }` and use that for indirectly modifying ID =)